# jQuery(this).find(div:first).outerWidth IE 8 bug

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Following is the code :

```
var b = this;
b.children("li").each(function() {
    var c = jQuery(this).find("div:first");
    var g = c.outerWidth();
    alert(g);
}
```

the value that the alert statement throws up is a constant value '3' for each iteration, though it should be different. Bug only in IE8. Reasons and any fix?

Comment: Can you attach HTML as well? Also which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Also what is `this` in your case?

Comment: How does this work in other browsers? `b` is not a jQuery object.

Comment: @undefined - if it's inside something like `$.fn.myplugin = ...` it would be, otherwise I agree!

Comment: The value returned by outerWith(), width() or .css("width") depends of your browser.

Comment: Also - just as an important side note - please considering using console commands such as `console.log` for debugging your applications. The console is much more powerful tool for debugging JavaScript applications and is widely available on modern browsers (and is available even in IE8 with F12 developer tools open).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `div` takes up the entire width of its parent element. So all div's will have the same width:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fwHe5/1/

Now, if you change that so that div's float left and are relativly positioned, they no longer take up the entire width.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fwHe5/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. `outerWidth` returns "the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding and border" [[1]](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/).

It just happens that in IE8 the content has different width than in other browsers due to rendering differences.

You can validate this behaviour by specifying a fixed width to your divs (such as `width: 640px`), which will result in consistent behaviour in all browsers. For demonstrations look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/y5Uur/1/